# DynamoDB // Lambda // Inconsistent Records

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

We push data to DynamoDB from our application based on events. We have written a lambda functional that Is mapped to this DynamoDB table. The records we update in our application successfully gets sent to DyanamoDB. However, lambda often time gives less number of records.

If there are 3 records updated in our application, all three gets pushed to Dynamo, but lambda sometimes gives only two or one.

We build a csv file in the lambda function, and as a result the csv file also has less number of records.

I can share some code snippet, but I am clueless if this has to do anything with the Lambda configuration or something with the Dynamo APIs we use to push data to Dynamo?

Following is the Lambda code:

```
public class ProductLambda implements RequestHandler<DynamodbEvent, String> {
    private static final String M_NUM = "number";
    private static final String FT_TABLE = "table";
    private AmazonS3 s3 = 
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
    private static final String S3_BUCKET = "bucket";
    private static final String S3_FOLDER = "folder";

public ProductLambda() {
}

@Override
public String handleRequest(DynamodbEvent event, Context context) {
    String[] appcol = new String[] {"COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4"};
    String[] fttcol = new String[] {"COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4"};
    
    createFolder(S3_BUCKET, S3_FOLDER, s3);
    List<DynamodbStreamRecord> records = event.getRecords();
    try {
        List<LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue>> changedRecords = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue>>();
        String ddbTable = "";
        for (DynamodbStreamRecord record : records) {
            String modelNumber = "";
            String ddbARN = record.getEventSourceARN();
            if (ddbARN != null) {
                ddbTable = ddbARN.split("/")[1];
            }
            if (record != null) {
                Map<String, AttributeValue> changedRec = record.getDynamodb().getNewImage();
                if (changedRec != null) {
                    if (ddbTable.equalsIgnoreCase("table1")) {
                        LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue> staticColumnRecord = new LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
                        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(appcol));
                        for (String key : list1) {
                            AttributeValue value = changedRec.get(key);
                            if (value != null) {
                                staticColumnRecord.put(key, value);
                            } else {
                                staticColumnRecord.put(key, new AttributeValue().withS("null"));
                            }
                        }
                        changedRecords.add(staticColumnRecord);
                    }
                    if (ddbTable.equalsIgnoreCase("table2")) {
                        LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue> staticColumnRecord = new LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
                        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fttcol));
                        for (String key : list2) {
                            AttributeValue value = changedRec.get(key);
                            if(key.equals("ft_mod")){
                                modelNumber = value.getS();
                            }
                            if (value != null) {
                                staticColumnRecord.put(key, value);
                            } else {
                                staticColumnRecord.put(key, new AttributeValue().withS("null"));
                            }
                        }
                        staticColumnRecord = getModelDetails(staticColumnRecord,modelNumber);
                        changedRecords.add(staticColumnRecord);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        context.getLogger().log("[DEBUG] - Total Records Changed: " + changedRecords.size());
        buildAndUploadCSV(changedRecords, context, ddbTable);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        context.getLogger().log("[ERROR] - AmazonServiceException " + e);
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
        context.getLogger().log("[ERROR] - AmazonClientException " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        context.getLogger().log("[ERROR] - IOException " + e);
    }
    context.getLogger().log("[DEBUG] - Total Records are: " + records.size());
    return "Total records are: " + records.size();
}

/*
 * 
 * @param staticColumnRecord
 * @param modelNumber
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
private LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue> getModelDetails(LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue> staticColumnRecord,
        String modelNumber) {

    String[] modcol = new String[] { "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4" };
    if (!modelNumber.isEmpty()) {
        AmazonDynamoDB dynamoClient = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
        GetItemRequest getItemRequest = new GetItemRequest().withTableName(FT_TABLE)
                .addKeyEntry(M_NUM, new AttributeValue().withS(modelNumber));
        Map<String, AttributeValue> responseItem = dynamoClient.getItem(getItemRequest).getItem();
        List<String> sf_mode_col = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(modcol));
        if (responseItem != null) {
            for (String key : sf_mode_col) {
                AttributeValue val = responseItem.get(key);
                if (val != null) {
                    staticColumnRecord.put(key, val);
                } else {
                    staticColumnRecord.put(key, new AttributeValue().withS("null"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return staticColumnRecord;
}

/*
 * Creates a folder in the S3 bucket.
 */
private static void createFolder(String bucketName, String folderName, AmazonS3 client) {
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentLength(0);
    InputStream emptyContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, folderName, emptyContent, metadata);
    PutObjectResult result = client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
}

/*
 * Build CSV file of changed data and upload to S3 bucket.
 */
private void buildAndUploadCSV(List<LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue>> changedRecords, Context context, String tableName)
        throws IOException {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    String outputName = tableName + "_" + formatter.format(calendar.getTime()) + ".csv";
    List<String> headers = changedRecords.stream().flatMap(map -> map.keySet().stream()).distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Path filePath = Paths.get("/tmp", outputName);
    try (OutputStreamWriter bw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath.toFile()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) 
    {
        StringBuffer headerContent = new StringBuffer();
        for (String string : headers) {
            headerContent.append(string);
            headerContent.append(",");
        }
        if (headerContent.length() > 0  && headerContent.charAt(headerContent.length() - 1) == ',')
            headerContent.setLength( headerContent.length() - 1 );

        StringBuffer strBuilder = new StringBuffer();
        for (LinkedHashMap<String, AttributeValue> lmap : changedRecords) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
            String sep = "";
            for (Entry<String, AttributeValue> string2 : lmap.entrySet()) {
                String value = string2.getValue().getS();
                stringBuilder.append(sep).append("\"").append(value).append("\"");
                sep = ",";
            }
            if (!stringBuilder.toString().isEmpty()) {
                strBuilder.append(stringBuilder).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        }
        headerContent.append("\n");
        headerContent.append(strBuilder);
        ByteArrayInputStream contentsAsStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(headerContent.toString().getBytes());
        ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();   
        md.setContentLength((long)headerContent.toString().getBytes().length);   
        md.setContentType("text/csv");
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest("bucket", "folder/" + outputName,
                contentsAsStream, md);
        s3.putObject(request);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        context.getLogger().log("[ERROR] - IOException " + e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: share your lambda code

Comment: What do you mean by "a lambda functional that Is mapped to this DynamoDB table"? Are you referring to capturing table activity via DynamoDB Streams which triggers a Lambda function?

Comment: @jarmod Correct.

Comment: @Nonik Just updated my post with the code.

Comment: Multiple Lambda invocations can happen. For example, the 1st invocation could contain a batch of 1 DDB updates and the 2nd invocation could contain a batch of 2 DDB updates. This would presumably cause multiple CSVs to be generated. What evidence do you have for streams updates being missing?

Comment: @jarmod I updated some data in our system that sent/updated 8 records to DynamoDB. We printed the records in our lambda logs and verified the logs' output on the console. Sometimes, there were only 6 records, sometimes 7. The generated CSV(s) also have less number of records.

Comment: Yes, it does generate multiple CSVs, and that is fine. But after all CSV generation, the number of records is less. Do you think some static code/variables in the lambda could cause this issue?

Comment: It's likely that your code is wrong or your understanding of what is happening is wrong. The alternative would be that DynamoDB Streams and/or Lambda are wrong which, while certainly possible, seems extremely unlikely. At the very least, print out `records.size()` so that you know how many streams records were actually present across all Lambda invocations.

Comment: @jarmod I'll print the size. Anything would you recommend to resolve this issue?

Comment: @jarmod I am printing the size. `context.getLogger().log("[DEBUG] - Total Records Changed: " + changedRecords.size());`

Comment: That’s not necessarily the same thing as `records.size()` because the code that populates `changedRecords` is conditional.